# Endforeach loop different class for first item

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not that good at php. What i have is a list of items looped with endforeach. What I want is that the first loop will have a class of col-lg-12 and from the second one that class will become col-lg-6. How can I achive that?

Here's the code:

```
<?php $firstLoop = true; 
foreach( $network_value as $key => $value ){

if( $firstLoop ){
    echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';
}

    echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';

$firstLoop = false;
} ?>
```

^This is the code that I've tried, but it's not working how i wanted.

```
            <?php if ($img): ?>
            <img src="<?php  echo $thumb->src ?>" width="<?php  echo $thumb->width ?>" height="<?php  echo $thumb->height ?>" alt="" />
        <?php endif; ?>
                <h4>
                    <div class="circle"><?php echo $datePublic = date('d M', strtotime($page->getCollectionDatePublic())); ?></div>
                    <br>
                   <a class="blogTitle" href="<?php echo $url ?>" target="<?php echo $target ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a></h4>
                <h6>Posted by <?php echo $author; ?></h6>
                <br>
                <p><?php echo $description ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: you should post the code and explain what you have attempted to solve the problem

Comment: foreach will only iterate once, sounds like you need 2 iterations to achieve what you need so you need to nest this iteration inside another that iterates columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to do it is to add a counter and check if it is the first value in the counter.

```
<?php 
  $counter = 0;
  foreach( $network_value as $key => $value )
  {
    if($counter == 0){
      echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
    }
    $counter++;
  } 
?>
```

Also I want to add that there are two ways of using foreach and if-statements, but you are trying to mix them, which is wrong.

The first method is using brackets "{" and "}":

```
foreach($users as $user) {
  // do things for each user
  echo $user->name; // Example of writing out users name
}
```

And if-statement:

```
if(true) {
  // do something
}
```

The second method is using "foreach(statement):" and "endforeach;"

```
foreach($users as $user):
  // do things for each user
  echo $user->name; // Example of writing out users name
endforeach;
```

And if-statement:

```
if(true):
  // do something
endif;
```

Comment: It's working, but it's not closing the div. It's loading all the posts and then it's closing all the divs. `<div class="col-lg-12"><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="col-lg-6"><div class="col-lg-6"><img src="/files/cache/8a19fb04f310351df5a598448253742a_f3.jpg" alt="" height="34" width="64"><h4><div class="circle">07 Sep</div><br><a class="blogTitle" href="/index.php/frettir/gasags/" target="_self">gasags</a></h4><h6>Posted by admin</h6><br><p>gsa</p></div></div></div></div></div>` It's giving me this code 7 times ( I have 7 posts)

Comment: Made it without foreach `<?php 
  {
    if($counter == 0){
      echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
    }
    $counter++;
  } 
?> ` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
In your case you can use:

```
<?php  
foreach ($pages as $key=>$page):
 if($key==0){
 echo '<div class="col-lg-12">'; 
 } if($key==1){
 echo '<div class="col-lg-6">'; 
 } 
endforeach; ?>
```

Or you can use:

```
<?php  
    foreach ($pages as $key=>$page):
     if($key==0){
     echo '<div class="col-lg-12">'; 
     } else {
     echo '<div class="col-lg-6">'; 
     } 
    endforeach; ?>
```

**OLD:**

```
foreach($array as $key=>$row){
 if($key==0){
  echo '<div class="col-lg-12"></div>';
 }
 if($key==5){
  echo '<div class="col-lg-6"></div>';
 }
// OR try use %
if($key%2 == 0){
  echo '<div class="col-lg-12"></div>';
 } else {
  echo '<div class="col-lg-12"></div>';
}
```

Comment: I've posted the code above. So, for the first time I want to get the code "<div class="col-lg-12>" and starting from the second one to get the "<div class="col-lg-6>" without the "<div class="col-lg-12">

Comment: See my first example with $key==0 :)
It's a first loop only!
$key==1 is second loop, $key==2 is third and .....

Comment: Can you help me a little bit? I don't have php knowledge. I have `<?php foreach ($pages as $page):?>` then I've put `<?php foreach($array as $key=>$row){
 if($key==0){
  echo '<div class="col-lg-12">';
 }
 if($key==1){
  echo '<div class="col-lg-6">';
 } ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>` and then I have the code above. But it's giveing me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in /var/www/virtual/nomos.is/htdocs/blocks/page_list/templates/thumbnail_images.php on line 68 ( that's the line with `<?php endif; ?>`